# Temporarily set anchor point of UIView, until after keyframe animation

Tags: uiview, point, cakeyframeanimation

Setting the anchor point of my UIView (to 0.5, 1.0) causes all sorts of issues with my layout. Can't I just temporarily change it for as long as I need it to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up moving this down 50% of the view's height, so it looks correct. It's a hack-fix but it works.